# Create Qt3D C++ scene with two viewports which displays different meshes appropriate

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt3d

Is it possible to show 3D scene with two viewports who will be drawn over each other and to display different meshes appropriate with different cameras using QtWidgets/C++ ?

Can someone share some code example how to make that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Using framegraphs:**

Essentially, you need to add two [`QViewPorts`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qviewport.html) to your framegraph where e.g. one covers the left half and the other the right half of the screen. Along the branches, you can use two different [`QCameraSelectors`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qcameraselector.html). I guess by drawn over each other you mean next to each other, I don't think you can actually draw them over each other.

There's the [Qt3D Multiviewport example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-multiviewport-example.html). It's in QML but should be easily translatable to QML.

Then you can point one camera at the first object and another camera at the second object and simply place them somewhere differently in 3D space.

**Using two Qt3DWindows**:

Simply use two Qt3DWindows next to each other and embed them.

Comment: Thanks for the response Florian. I know that examples, and already implemented that QML example in my source example, but in the viewports I have same mesh. How to implement different meshes at the viewports using C++? Example: I want to show in the first viewport coordinate system and in the second torus mesh.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can't make one object appear different for one viewport but have to use two objects at different locations.

Comment: Good idea is your edit of the answer, thanks @Florian Blume